# How to find Shadow-root element using locators in Selenium 4.10?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, shadow-dom

`enter code here`It seems only **CssSelector** and **className** is valid for Shadow Dom root elements. But if there is no attribute to use. How to grab "Get Text 1" and "Get Text 2" ?

Below is the HTML tree

```
<br-map style="display: block; class="hydrated"></br-map>
    #shadow-root (root)
        <div class="pageDemo">
            <ul css="1">
                <li> Get Text 1</li>
                <li> Get Text 2</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
</br-map>
```

```java
WebElement shadowHost1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//br-map"));        
SearchContext shadowRoot1 = shadowHost1.getShadowRoot();
shadowRoot1.findElement(By.xpath("//ul/li")).getText())
```

;// xpath Don't work (org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException)`

Comment: Update the question with the parent element of the `#shadow-root (root)` element